# Which formatter is called when format documentation

Tags: visual-studio-code

In vscode when **Format document**, how do I know exatly which plugin is doing the work behind it?

I want to know this information to correctly setting the formattting style for some file type..

Comment: If you search settings for `format`, you will see that a lot of format options are available for: html, css, javascript, typescript, dart, python. All others are provided as an extension and document will format if those extensions are installed.

Comment: Yes, I know those, they look like a bunch of mess, that is why I ask this question.  I remember when I use atom, I could check exactly what action is bind to the shortcut, and then to start deeper debug, but vscode don't have this ability. feel sad.